# The explicit event which gives distinguisher between two distributions

Tags: machine-learning

I am very very new in machine learning. Suppose two distributions generate binary numbers. For the 1st distribution, 0 occurs with a probability of 0.5; for 2nd, it is 0.51.
I generate data from both and train. Then I create data from both and test the
accuracy. It gives some accuracy. nstead of black box, I want to find the event by which it internally distinguishes the distributions. I use tensor flow.

Comment: One of the downsides of Neural Networks you use (from Tensorflow) is they're a "black box", you can't really understand where the prediction comes from. If you want to analyze the difference of predictions from one set to another, you should use easier models, allowing prediction explaination (example : Logistic Regression, which gives you access to coefficiens, so you can understand the prediction)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will you kindly suggest some study materials for these?

Comment: It depends the level of explanation you need. Some modules tend to explain predictions of any model (Lime or Shap with Shapley Values), but the easier is to use "simple" algorithms. Logistic Regression is a good idea so you look at coefficients. Decision Tree is easy to understand also. Even Random Forest can give an overview if you look all trained trees of the forest (even though it might not be the best choice). I don't specifically know any article to read about the problem.

Comment: Using any machine learning model to represent a [Bernouilli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) is an overkill. Also you may or may not have a confusion about what the model does here: do you realize that in your example every instance must be a long sequence of binary digits, not a single digit?

Comment: Yes, it is a long sequence of binary digits.